# Excel CreateObject Procedure Not Found | "Run-time Error '-2147024769 (8007007f)"

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Hi I am trying to run a very simple Microsoft Excel Macro, the code shown below:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Workbooks.Add

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"
```

However I continue to receive the following error:

```
Run-time Error '-2147024769 (8007007f)':

Automation Error

The specified procedure could not be found
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this? After some digging, its something to do with the COM.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: **How** are you running that code?

Comment: In Excel VBA (as opposed to e.g.  VBScript) there is almost never a good reason to have the line `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: I am running in the VBA application.  I tried running the same script on a different computer (Excel 2010 version), and it works perfectly.

Comment: Then the code you have posted is incomplete and you still haven't said **how** you are calling it.

Comment: I have the impression that you are running regular VB code from inside a VBA environment.

Comment: Or are you running this code from inside Excel?  If so, then you don't need to create an Excel object because you're already running inside of one.

Comment: Yes I am running this from inside Microsoft Excel.  I create a new Macro workbook, and use this code.  Basically this code is supposed to open a new Excel window and put "Test Value" in cell (1,1)

Comment: Open a new instance of the Excel application (is that what you mean by the Excel window?), or create a new Excel workbook within the current instance of the Excel application?

Comment: The latter, It opens up a brand new Excel workbook

Answer (score 1):

You are already in Excel so all you need is

```
sub demo
Workbooks.Add()
Range("A1")="Test Value"
End Sub
```

Your code would work in Word however - where it would open Excel, then a workbook and then write to A1.

Comment: @Jeeped It *is* a property of `Application`.